# Webmaster tools doesn't detect structured data on my website

Tags: google-search-console, rich-snippets, structured-data, google-rich-snippets

It has been a while since I upload all my webpages.  Google in fact has indexed them too and my website has started appearing in the Google search results.  But still Webmaster tools shows that the data on my site is unstructured. How can I rectify this?  I had tested all my web pages with the rich snippets tools provided by Google and the test was successful because Google correctly showed me the extracted data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The structured data numbers that are reported in Webmaster Tools are rarely correct.  In fact, sometimes the numbers are way, way off.  So as long as your page contains structured data markup in the code and as long as Google's testing tool is picking it up, you're fine.  No need to be overly concerned about it.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering about this problem since a long time.

Comment: Yeah, it's a frequently complained about problem, but it's nothing to really worry about.